# how to interchanging data between online mysql database and offline mysql database via c# windows forms application?

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, winforms, server

how to interchanging data between online mysql database and offline mysql database via c# windows forms application?

1. online database and offline database is same tables and fields
2. every one hour updating or interchanging data between online mysql database and offline mysql database.
3. how can connect online Mysql database via c# windows forms application?

anybody help me please....

Answer (score 0):

1 : It's up to your library for connect MySQL database. To interchange data it just you SELECT from source DB then UPDATE to destination DB

2 : There are a class Timer you could use to schedule hourly to run function you want

3 : Most of library to connect MySQL would support remote connection, just get the IP of target MySQL DB. It not relate to programming now, It's about IT setup that will provide you IP and Port for making connection

Comment: please give example code to connect. like MySqlConnection con1 = new MySqlConnection("Server=xxxxxx.com; Database=ffff; Uid=dddd; Pwd=yyyy;");  this is not connect.

Comment: Then you should use try/catch or any kind of debugging to specified the error first. I guess there maybe firewall or connection problem. First you should try connect to that database with normal MySQL connection tool